# how to changed editext values from first to last in customise listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

i am getting menunames from database then append to the custom listview edittext . now i am changing some values in edittext . i want all values with changed values of edittext into array

```
           Example :x,y,z menunames comes from database i append editext(Custom listview)
           now i am changed y to b 
           now i want x,b,z in arraylist
```

i try this code(Base adapter class)

```
           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
        holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
        holder.caption1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
    holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);
    holder.caption.setId(position);
    holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);


    arr.add(holder.caption.getText().toString());//here i get menunames data only not changed edittext values



    return convertView;
}
  }

 class ViewHolder {
EditText caption;
ImageView caption1;
}

 class ListItem {
String caption;
 }
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Keep the data in arraylist and after changing the text in arraylist call the listview once again using adapter as follows

```
      lv.invalidate(); // it will rebuilt all the views in listview
      adapter=new adapterclass(this);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it will change the value of listview and call the invalidateview method of listview it will change the data of listview. Try it. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

if the new data has been come from database then you have to call the cursor again & 
setAdapter again to the listView..

or if the data is already in the array list so you just used to invalidate the listView.
n set the Adapter again....
you'll get what you want...